# Android Studio, Thread is starting over and over again

Tags: java, android, multithreading

a newbie here.

I made a thread(i will call main thread after this moment) which controls the time with 1000ms sleep and changes some variables in the main activity.And i show that variables in the layout.

Somehow, while main thread is working, i need to go another activity and then need to return to main activity.

theorically i know that, thread doesnt stop. ok thats good for me, i need that variables to change anytime with the algorithm.

But when i go another activity and then return to Main Thread's activity, variables are changing like maint thread started 2nd time.. All variables getting 2x times bigger then what they must be. when i go  another activity and return to main 3rd time, variables are changing 3x times bigger.
In the other activity i use just this code nothing else;

```
startActivity(new Intent(n7Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
```

i want to ask that, Just assume i start a thread in the main activity, then i go to another activity with classical intent method,(by the way i dont use any on pause method or smthg.) then when i return to main activity, is the same thread starts 2nd time while the first thread is still working?

thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`startActivity()` creates a new Activity instance. I think should to call `finish()` in another Activity to back to the main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

> when i return to main activity, is the same thread starts 2nd time while the first thread is still working?

It seems so.

What method do your create your thread in? If it were in `onCreate`, your thread will be created only once, since `onCreate` is called only once in the activity lifecycle.

Nonetheless I'd suggest you to use a [`Timer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or a [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead. They have features that are exactly what you need. You don't need to manually dispatch a thread in this case.

It's also important to pay attention to the activity lifecycle, so no thread would be consuming CPU for an activity that is not in the foregrond. You should stop the timer when the `OnPause` is called on the activity, for example.

#### UPDATE

Actually you can schedule a repeating task in a `Timer`. Here's an example:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Timer mMyTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mMyTimer = new Timer();
        // 0L means "start right now".
        // 1000L is the period between executions in ms.
        mMyTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // It's a background thread, so
                // don't update the UI directly from here.
                doStuff();
            }
        }, 0L, 1000L);
    }

    Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mMyTimer.cancel();
        mMyTimer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment,
it is oncreate method.
i cant use timer because it is a repeating task.
and i sitll dont know what to do..